# Nested Select vs CTE for Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, common-table-expression

---

with CTEs

---

```
;with TERMS_DAYS AS 
(
    SELECT *
    ,replace(RIGHT(TERMS, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '') AS DUE
    ,CASE WHEN replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '') < 10  THEN 30 ELSE 
     CASE WHEN replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '')  > 45  THEN replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '') + 30 
     ELSE replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '')  * 3 END 
        END                                         AS ELIGIBLE_T
    ,DATEDIFF(DD,"DATE",@p_DATE)                    AS t_DAYS
    FROM #t_BBC_LOAD
)
, ELIGIBLE AS 
(   
    SELECT *
            ,CASE WHEN 91 < t_DAYS THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS [CURRENT]
    FROM TERMS_DAYS
)
, FOREIGN_TOTALS AS 
(
    SELECT   CUSTOMER
            ,COUNTRY
            ,SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT
            ,[CURRENT]
            ,MS
    FROM ELIGIBLE
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER, COUNTRY, [CURRENT], MS
)
, TOTALS AS 
(
SELECT   CUSTOMER
        ,COUNTRY
        ,ISNULL(Y,0) Y
        ,ISNULL(N,0) N
        ,MS
FROM FOREIGN_TOTALS
)
select * from TOTALS
  PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [CURRENT] IN (Y, N)) AS P
```

---

WITHOUT CTEs

---

```
SELECT 
     Customer
    ,Country
    ,isnull(Y,0) as Y
    ,isnull(N,0) as N
    ,MS
FROM(
     SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNTRY, sum(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT, [CURRENT], MS
     FROM (
            SELECT *
            ,CASE WHEN 91 < t_DAYS THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS [CURRENT] --Eligble
            FROM(SELECT *
                ,replace(RIGHT(TERMS, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '') AS DUE
                ,CASE WHEN replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '') < 10  THEN 30 ELSE 
                 CASE WHEN replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '')  > 45  THEN replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '') + 30 
                 ELSE replace(RIGHT(Terms, LEN(terms) - 5), '-', '')  * 3 END 
                    END                                         AS ELIGIBLE
                ,DATEDIFF(DD,"DATE",@p_DATE)                    AS t_DAYS
                FROM #t_BBC_LOAD)
    EXP12G) ESGS

GROUP BY CUSTOMER, COUNTRY, [CURRENT], MS) as exp34
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [CURRENT] IN (Y, N)) AS P;
go
```

The "without CTEs" or "woCTE" runs fine. I've been tasked to clean up and reassign some values elsewhere in the original query. However, I've run in to a snag.
The woCTE code runs and recognizes the nested "y" and "n" references even though they don't exist in the final select. When I run (what I think) is an equivalent CTE, it won't recognize the "y/n" references. How is it storing the columnar data with it being selected?

I'm running 2019, and the original code is from 2011 but again, ran slow but complete when I started revising it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select * was deleted, and isn't used. The pivot needs the specific fields used in the pivot function. My bad.